# The probability of throwing $n$ dice with each result being contained in a set

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

I recently asked this question on MSE: [The probability of throwing two dice with each result being contained in a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4441296/the-probability-of-throwing-two-dice-with-each-result-being-contained-in-a-set)
and although I am happy with the answer, I cannot figure out how this generalizes to $n$ or even 3 dice.

**To state the case for $n$ dice:**
If we have the sets $S_1, S_2, \dots, S_n$ of possible outcomes and we throw $n$ indistinguishable dice (with the same number of sides) simultaneously, what is the probability that each die is contained in different sets, that is, what is the probability that the first is contained in set $S_{i_1}$, the second is contained in $S_{i_2}$, the third in $S_{i_3}$, $\dots$ and the $n$-th in $S_{i_n}$ with $i_1 \neq i_2 \neq i_3 \neq \dots \neq i_n$.

**An example for $n=2$:** When have 2 dice and two sets $A$ and $B$ being $\{ 1, 2, 4\}$ and $\{ 1, 2, 5\}$, respectively.
We will end up with the possibilities of $\{ 1,1 \}, \{ 2,2 \}$ which account for a $\frac{1}{36}$ probability each and  $\{ 1,2 \}$, $\{ 1,4 \}$, $\{ 1,5 \}$, $\{ 2,4 \}$, $\{ 2,5 \}$, $\{ 4,5 \}$ accounting for a $\frac{2}{36}$ probability each, for a total chance of $\frac{14}{36}=\frac{7}{18}$. As @user2661923 correctly pointed out in the other question, you could also determine this by calculating $\frac{(2\times 3^2) - 2^2}{36} = \frac{14}{36} = \frac{7}{18}$.

**Formula for $n=2$:** In general the chance for $n=2$ dice with sets $A$ and $B$ is:
$$\frac{2! \# A \# B - \#(A\cap B)^2}{6^2}$$.

**Formula for $n=3$:** This is where I got stuck, I could not obtain the formula for three dice with the sets $A$, $B$ and $C$. However, I came this far:
$$\frac{3! \#A \#B \#C - 3\#A\#(B\cap C)^2 - 3\#B\#(A\cap C)^2 - 3\#C\#(A\cap B)^2 \pm \dots}{6^3}$$
I do not know what should be at the dots.

**My question:** What is the correct formula for $n=3$ (and for larger $n$)?

I also wrote some python code to check some cases and provide **support**, mostly so that double work is avoided; everthing can be controlled by changing the variable `sets` (add anoter list to add a die).

```
from itertools import product
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations
from collections import Counter


# sets = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
sets = [[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5]]

n_dice = len(correct)
counter = Counter()

for roll in product(range(1, max(max(i) for i in sets)+1), repeat=n_dice):
    times = 0
    for perm in multiset_permutations(roll):
        if [perm[i] in sets[i] for i in range(n_dice)] == [True]*n_dice:
            times = 1
    if times > 0:
        counter[tuple(sorted(roll))] += times

count = 0
for k, v in sorted(counter.items()):
    count += v
    print(f'total: {count}, dice roll: {k}, multiplicity: {v}')
```

Comment: Beats me.  It is obviously going to be affected both by the size of each of the sets $S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_n$ as well as the partial and/or full overlaps among $S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_n$.  I use *partial overlap* to signify that a certain element is in more than $1$ but less than $n$ of the sets, and I use *full overlap* to signify that the element is in all $n$ of the sets.

Comment: Also no thoughts for the case $n=3$? I would think that the working out would still be manageable (although I did not manage it).

Comment: Yes.  My thoughts are that when $n=3$, the problem is very difficult.  Partial overlaps are killers.

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize the inner loop by framing the problem as finding a perfect matching on a bipartite graph where the left-side vertexes are the dice and the right-side vertexes are the sets, and edge $\left(i, j\right)$ exists iff the number rolled on die $i$ is in set $S_j$. A perfect matching thus corresponds to an assignment of a unique die to each set as desired. This can then be solved using e.g. the [Hopcroft-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).

Since you can generate any bipartite graph in this way, the non-triviality of such algorithms suggests that there is no expression for the general case that is both efficient and "closed-form".

You can reduce the outer loop by replacing the full Cartesian product with iterating through the possible multisets, since the dice are indistinguishable. Unfortunately I don't have any further ideas off the top of my head for the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

To give a partial answer to my own question:

After much tweeking I got the formula for $n=3$ with the sets denoted by $A$, $B$ and $C$, it is given by (note you still have to divide by $6^3$):
\begin{multline} \\
    3!\#A\#B\#C \\
 - 3\#A\#(B\cap C)^2\\
 - 3\#B\#(A\cap C)^2\\
 - 3\#C\#(A\cap B)^2\\
    +4\#(A\cap B \cap C)^3 \\
    +3\#(A\cap B \cap C)^2(\#(A\cap B)+\#(B\cap C)+\#(A\cap C)-3\#(A\cap B \cap C))\\
    - 6 (\#(A\cap B) - \#(A\cap B \cap C)) (\#(B\cap C) - \#(A\cap B \cap C)) (\#(A\cap C) - \#(A\cap B \cap C))
\end{multline}
Which we can shorten a bit when we define $\#A = A$, $\#B = B$ and $\#C = C$, as well as $\#(A\cap B) = AB$, $\dots$ and $\#(A\cap B\cap C) = ABC$. Note that we will use a $\times$ to denote multiplication (instead of leaving it), that gives:
\begin{multline}\\
    3!\times A\times B \times C - 3\times A\times BC^2 - 3\times B\times AC^2 - 3\times C\times AB^2+4\times ABC^3 \\
    +3\times ABC^2(AB+BC+AC-3\times ABC)- 6 \times (AB - ABC) \times (BC - ABC) \times (AC - ABC)
\end{multline}

I verified this formula for many, many cases, but I did not get an intuitive feel for its validity, nor was able to formulate a proof.

With this case written out, I don't think the generalization would be easy on the eyes. However, this might give an idea how larger cases would work.

---

**Update:** Although I could not fully determine the coefficients for the case $n=4$, here is what I know so far (I plan on changing this once I know more), using the notation from above and noting that you still have to divide by $6^4$:
\begin{gather}
4! \times S_1 \times S_2 \times S_3 \times S_4 - \\
12 \times [S_3\times S_4\times (S_1S_2)^2 + S_2\times S_4\times (S_1S_3)^2 + S_2\times S_3\times (S_1S_4)^2 + \\
S_1\times S_4\times (S_2S_3)^2 + S_1\times S_3\times (S_2S_4)^2 + S_1\times S_2\times (S_3S_4)^2] + \\
6\times [(S_1S_2)^2 \times (S_3S_4)^2+(S_1S_3)^2 \times (S_2S_4)^2+(S_1S_4)^2 \times (S_2S_3)^2] -\\
24\times [(S_1S_2)\times (S_1S_3) \times (S_1S_4) \times(S_2S_3) + (S_1S_2)\times (S_1S_3) \times (S_1S_4) \times(S_2S_4) + \\(S_1S_2)\times (S_1S_3) \times (S_1S_4) \times(S_3S_4) + (S_1S_2)\times (S_1S_3) \times (S_2S_3) \times(S_2S_4) + \\(S_1S_2)\times (S_1S_3) \times (S_2S_3) \times(S_3S_4) + (S_1S_2)\times (S_1S_3) \times (S_2S_4) \times(S_3S_4) + \\(S_1S_2)\times (S_1S_4) \times (S_2S_3) \times(S_2S_4) + (S_1S_2)\times (S_1S_4) \times (S_2S_3) \times(S_3S_4) + \\(S_1S_2)\times (S_1S_4) \times (S_2S_4) \times(S_3S_4) + (S_1S_2)\times (S_2S_3) \times (S_2S_4) \times(S_3S_4) + \\(S_1S_3)\times (S_1S_4) \times (S_2S_3) \times(S_2S_4) + (S_1S_3)\times (S_1S_4) \times (S_2S_3) \times(S_3S_4) + \\(S_1S_3)\times (S_1S_4) \times (S_2S_4) \times(S_3S_4) + (S_1S_3)\times (S_2S_3) \times (S_2S_4) \times(S_3S_4) + \\(S_1S_4)\times (S_2S_3) \times (S_2S_4) \times(S_3S_4)] + \\
16 \times [S_1\times (S_2S_3S_4)^3+S_2\times (S_1S_3S_4)^3+S_3\times (S_1S_2S_4)^3+S_4\times (S_1S_2S_3)^3] + \\
12 \times [S_4 \times (S_1S_2S_3)^2\times(S_1S_2 + S_2S_3 + S_1S_3 - 3\times S_1S_2S_3)) + \\
S_3 \times (S_1S_2S_4)^2\times(S_1S_2 + S_2S_4 + S_1S_4 - 3\times S_1S_2S_4)) + \\
S_2 \times (S_1S_3S_4)^2\times(S_1S_3 + S_3S_4 + S_1S_4 - 3\times S_1S_3S_4)) + \\
S_1 \times (S_2S_3S_4)^2\times(S_2S_3 + S_3S_4 + S_2S_4 - 3\times S_2S_3S_4))] + \\
327 \times (S_1S_2S_3S_4)^4 \pm \dots
\end{gather}

Some compacter notation would also be welcome. Especially for the first few terms this seems possible to me because the terms sort of "cycle" through all permutations. Even the large middle term with $24$ in front of it just cycles through the combinations of picking four elements from $S_1S_2$, $S_1S_3$, $S_1S_4$, $S_2S_3$, $S_2S_4$, $S_3S_4$ which are $6$ options, thus giving $\binom{6}{4}=15$ terms. It may be due to how I determined the last two known parts, but those just seem symmetric to me (they have to be because the dice are indistinguishable), not cycling through any combinations. This made determining the next coefficients very difficult.

---

**2nd Update:** The formula for $n=3$ can be rewritten to:
\begin{multline}
    3!\times A\times B \times C - 3\times [A\times BC^2 + B\times AC^2 + C\times AB^2] \\
-6 \times AB \times BC \times AC + 6 \times (AB\times AC + AB \times BC + AC \times BC) \times ABC \\
-3 \times (AB + AC + BC) \times ABC^2 + ABC^3
\end{multline}

---

**3rd Update:** I found the formula for $n=4$ (or rather, my computer did with my help). Note that you still have to divide by $6^4$ and that I have replaced $\times$ with $\cdot$ **(some compacter notation would really be appreciated)**:
\begin{gather}
24\cdot[S_1\cdot S_2\cdot S_3\cdot S_4]\\
-12\cdot[S_1\cdot S_2\cdot S_3S_4^2+S_1\cdot S_3\cdot S_2S_4^2+S_1\cdot S_4\cdot S_2S_3^2+S_2\cdot S_3\cdot S_1S_4^2+S_2\cdot S_4\cdot S_1S_3^2+S_3\cdot S_4\cdot S_1S_2^2]\\
-24\cdot[S_1\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4+S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_3S_4+S_3\cdot S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_4+S_4\cdot S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3]\\
24\cdot[S_1\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_3\cdot S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4+S_3\cdot S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4+S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4+S_4\cdot S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3+S_4\cdot S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3+S_4\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3]\\
-12\cdot[S_1\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2+S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2+S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2+S_2\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2+S_3\cdot S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2+S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2+S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2+S_4\cdot S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2+S_4\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2+S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2]\\
4\cdot[S_1\cdot S_2S_3S_4^3+S_2\cdot S_1S_3S_4^3+S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4^3+S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3^3]\\
6\cdot[S_1S_2^2\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_3S_4+S_1S_3^2\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_4+S_1S_4^2\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
-12\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2+S_1S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2+S_1S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2+S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2+S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2+S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
-12\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
-12\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
12\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
12\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2]\\
12\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_1S_2S_4]\\
-12\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
12\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
12\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2]\\
-4\cdot[S_1S_2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^3+S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^3+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^3+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^3+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^3+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^3]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_3\cdot S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4]\\
12\cdot[S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_1S_2S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_1S_2S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4]\\
24\cdot[S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4]\\
-6\cdot[S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_4+S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3S_4^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4]\\
-12\cdot[S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4]\\
12\cdot[S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3S_4^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
-6\cdot[S_1S_2S_3^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_2S_3S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
-12\cdot[S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_1S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2\cdot S_2S_3S_4]\\
12\cdot[S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
-12\cdot[S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4^2]\\
-24\cdot[S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4]\\
24\cdot[S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4+S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4]\\
-12\cdot[S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2+S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^2]\\
4\cdot[S_1S_2S_3\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^3+S_1S_2S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^3+S_1S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^3+S_2S_3S_4\cdot S_1S_2S_3S_4^3]\\
-1\cdot[S_1S_2S_3S_4^4]
\end{gather}

Comment: I just updated my answer to include the parts I know for the case $n=4$.